# Magento getPost() not passing the variable to the observer

Tags: php, magento, model, observers

Model Code:

```
class Excellence_File_Model_File extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
            {
                public function _construct()
                {
                    parent::_construct();
                    $this->_init('file/file');
                }

        public function saveFile($quote_id,$filename,$type){
    $this->getResource()->deleteFile($quote_id,$filename,$type);
    $this->setFilename($filename);
    $this->setQuoteId($quote_id);
    $this->setType($type);
    $this->save();
}

            }
```

Observer Code:

```
            public function saveQuoteAfter($evt){
                $quote = $evt->getQuote();

                $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

                if(isset($post['file_upload_path'])){
                    $quote_id = $quote->getId();
                    $filename = $post['file_upload_path'];
                    $type = $post['file_upload_type'];
                    Mage::log($quote_id.'xx'.$filename);
                    Mage::getModel('file/file')->saveFile($quote_id,$filename,$type);
                }
            }
        }
```

I looked at all the forums and nothing found, I need to post the variables to insert it in the database, I appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: Excellence_File_Model_File  is mode class.it is not contollrer

Comment: from which step are you checking?

Comment: Here is the link of the tutorial Im trying to implement [link] (http://excellencemagentoblog.com/onepage-checkout-add-file-upload-field-to-any-step)

Comment: @AmitBera Yes, sorry model code. Im checking from payment methods.